# remember a match in some previous line and print it just once and only if a consecutive line contains some match with sed

Tags: shell, awk, sed

sed magic wanted:

I wondered how to save/remember a match in a line (like a header part) without immediate printing it

and print it just if some other match of something else is found in a somewhere following line,

but the saved/remembered header part should only be printed once for any number of following other matches beneath that header

and it should not be printed at all, if there is no match of the other thing in any following line beneath that remembered header line

so for example for an `ifconfig`

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
    inet 127.94.0.2 netmask 0xff000000
    inet 127.94.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
XHC20: flags=0<> mtu 0
en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=10b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_HWTAGGING,AV>
    ether 68:5b:35:c1:b3:91
    inet6 fe80::8ef:5953:53b:7058%en3 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x5
    inet 192.168.0.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
    inet6 2a02:810d:9c0:59bb:c0d:c8af:7e27:42f1 prefixlen 64 autoconf secured
    inet6 2a02:810d:9c0:59bb:643f:a2cb:ac5f:7c71 prefixlen 64 autoconf temporary
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex,flow-control,energy-efficient-ethernet>)
    status: active
en0: flags=8823<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 6c:40:08:9c:45:ce
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (<unknown type>)
    status: inactive
```

with `ifconfig | gsed -n -E '/^[a-z0-9]*:/h; /\tinet (addr:)?[0-9.a-fA-F:]*/{x;p;x;p}'`

I get (which is pretty awesome already, but not nice):

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet 127.94.0.2 netmask 0xff000000
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    inet 127.94.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
en3: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.0.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.0.255
```

but I only want to get headers once for all its ips as a result (and no clutter)

```
lo0:
    inet 127.0.0.1
    inet 127.94.0.2
    inet 127.94.0.1
en3:
    inet 192.168.0.2
```

Comment: Don't parse ifconfig output, it's old. Move to `ip a`.

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following once.

```
Your_command | awk '
/^[a-zA-Z]+/{
  count=""
  val=$1
  next
}
val && match($0,/.*[0-9]+\.[-0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+ +/){
  if(++count==1){
    print val
  }
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  sub(/ +$/,"",value)
  print value
  value=""
}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

so I figured it out how to do it over the last night :)

```
ifconfig | gsed -n -E '
/^[a-z0-9]*:/ {                     # for lines starting with this
    s/^([a-z0-9]*:).*/\1/;h         # extract the start and put it into hold space
}
/\tinet (addr:)?[0-9.a-fA-F:]*/ {   # for lines containing this
    s/^.*(\tinet (addr:)?[0-9.a-fA-F:]*).*/\1/    # extract it
    x                               # swap hold space and pattern space
    G                               # and then append the hold space (former pattern space) to it 
    s/^\n//                         # replace leading \n if former hold space was empty
    p                               # print the concatenated former hold space and modified pattern space
    s/^.*$//                        # empty the pattern space
    x                               # swap the now empty pattern space to hold space
}
'
```

or as a (more or less) one-liner:

```
ifconfig | gsed -n -E '
/^[a-z0-9]*:/                   { s/^([a-z0-9]*:).*/\1/;h };
/\tinet (addr:)?[0-9.a-fA-F:]*/ { s/^.*(\tinet (addr:)?[0-9.a-fA-F:]*).*/\1/;x;G;s/^\n//;p;s/^.*$//;x}'
```

gives me the wished for

```
lo0:
    inet 127.0.0.1
    inet 127.94.0.2
    inet 127.94.0.1
en3:
    inet 192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have two suggestions for you:

1. When cleaning input lines, it is sometimes easier to remove rather than select.
2. In this case it is easier to collect the eventual output in hold-space.

E.g.:

*parse.sed*

```
/^[^ ]+/ {        # For lines starting with non-space
  x               # \
  /\n/p           #  Did we collect any IP addresses?
  x               # /

  s/ .*//         # Clean up interface name
  h               # Overwrite hold-space
}

/inet / {
  s/ netmask.*//
  H               # Collect ip addresses in hold-space
}

$ {
  x               # Print the last interface if
  /\n/p           # it contained IP addresses
}
```

Run it like this:

```
ifconfig | gsed -nEf parse.sed
```

Output:

```
lo0:
    inet 127.0.0.1
    inet 127.94.0.2
    inet 127.94.0.1
en3:
    inet 192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is for doing simple `s/old/new`, **that is all**, for anything else just use awk:

```
$ ifconfig | awk '/^[[:alpha:]]/{hdr=$1 ORS} $1=="inet"{print hdr "    " $1, $2; hdr=""}'
lo0:
    inet 127.0.0.1
    inet 127.94.0.2
    inet 127.94.0.1
en3:
    inet 192.168.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -En '/^\S/h;s/^(\s+inet\s+\S+).*/\1/;T;x;s/\s.*//p;x;p' file
```

Store the header line in the hold space.

Remove anything following the ip address for lines that contain `inet`.

If the substitution was unsuccessful, bail out. Otherwise, return to the hold space and try to remove the end of the header line and print it.

Return  to the pattern space and print the original ip address line.

N.B. The header will only be printed once because the substitution will fail once the line has already been edited.